# Затемнение тайловой карты

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Делаю игру, похожую та *terraria* или *starbound*. У меня есть две тайловые карты, одна передняя с коллайдером, а вторая задняя, как бы на фоне. Мне нужно, что бы для этих карт использовались **одинаковые палитры**, но тайлы на задней карте были темнее, чем на передней, можно ли это сделать без шейдера? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала разделите в одной сетке Tilemap на 2.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отключите у Tilemap заднего фона все возможные колайдеры, которые вы могли бы скопировать из первого. Затем у Tilemap заднего фона выставьте параметр **Color** темне, чем у основного Tilemap, а в Tilemap Renderer замените Order in Layer на значение меньше, чем у основного.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким образом можно плодить бесконечно слоев, использовать одну палитру и добиваться вот такого эффекта :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да, я уже нашёл эту функцию, всё оказалось очень просто, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблемму, между основной картой и задней, создал ещё одну карту, на которой ставятся полупрозрачные тёмные тайлы на координатах тайлов задней карты

Comment: @VictorVosMottor почему нет?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor тоесть коротковато? если это решило его проблему что еще можно добавить? может посоветуете АВТОРУ, а не будете копипастить сообщения где на подобии `Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у АВТОРА внести уточнения`.  Я за сегодня уже 4 таких комментария от вас заметил

Comment: @ВадимАлександру Это комменты из очереди, н я их придумал ;). А в очереди никто не разбирается с каждом вопросом, а смотрят на общие "характеристики", изредка бывают ошибки.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Тогда не проверяйте, раз вы думаете, что `Никто не разбирается с вопросом` и можно без какого либо основания объявить, что `это не является ответом ибо он сликом короткий`

Answer (score 0):

Есть решение намного проще, незнаю чего я всё усложнял. Выбрал заднюю карту и в инспекторе просто выставил цвет на серый.